# jQuery AJAX fails to update database after full page is finished loading

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

This is my first time using jQuery AJAX so bear with me. I am trying to create a like button for my website similar to the Facebook like button. A user must be logged on via Facebook which will pull their userid from my database. When a user clicks on the like button, it inserts a row into the database with the user info and the page info. If there is already an entry for the user and page, it will update the row.

My code runs perfectly fine on my localhost. I can click on the like button all day and the image will constantly change back and forth from like to unlike and back. The database updates every time as well with no problem.

When I upload this to my live server, the script runs perfectly fine as well to a point. Once my page finishes loading completely, the database no longer updates from the click. The images will change as usual and I will receive the alert('Success') but no changes are made to the actual database.

```
<?php
$tempstat = '1';
if ($stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("SELECT count(id)
    FROM votes
    WHERE businessid=? and status=? ")) {
    $stmt -> bind_param('ss', $businessid, $tempstat);
    $stmt -> execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($likecount);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close();
}
if ($likecount == '') { $likecount = 0; }
?>
<style>
#karmabar { padding-left: 4px; }
#counter { margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; width: 50px; height: 25px; background-image: url('/images/karma-counter.png'); }
p#counter { font-size: 12px; padding-top: 5px; }
.karma { margin: 0 auto; font-size: 16px; color: blue; text-align: center; padding: 5px; }
</style>
<?php
if(login_check($mysqli) == true) { 
$userid = $_SESSION['userurl']; 
if ($stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("SELECT status
    FROM votes
    WHERE userid=? and businessid=? ")) {
    $stmt -> bind_param('ss', $userid, $businessid);
    $stmt -> execute();
    $stmt -> bind_result($like_status);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close();
}
if ($like_status == '' or $like_status == NULL) { $like_status = '0'; }
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#like_post').click(function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "/includes/like.php",
        type: "GET",
        data: 'userid=<?php echo $userid; ?>&businessid=<?php echo $businessid; ?>&like_status=1',
        success: function() {
            alert("Success");
        },
        error: function() {
           alert("Something went wrong");
        }
      });
      $('#counter').html(function(i, val) { return val*1+1 });
      $('#like_post').hide();
      $('#unlike_post').show();
    });

  $('#unlike_post').click(function() {
     $.ajax({
        url: "/includes/like.php",
        type: "GET",
        data: 'userid=<?php echo $userid; ?>&businessid=<?php echo $businessid; ?>&like_status=0',
        success: function() {
            alert("Success");
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("Something went wrong");
        }
        });
      $('#counter').html(function(i, val) { return val*1-1 });
      $('#unlike_post').hide();
      $('#like_post').show();
  });
});
</script>
<div id="karmabar">
    <table cellpadding="0px">
        <?php if ($like_status == '0') { ?>
        <tr><td><a href="javascript:;" id="unlike_post" class="hide"><img src="/images/karma-active.png" title="Undo Karma" /></a><a href="javascript:;" id="like_post"><img src="/images/karma-inactive.png" title="Spread Karma" /></a><td><p id="counter"><?php echo $likecount; ?></p></td></tr>
        <?php } else { ?>
        <tr><td><a href="javascript:;" id="unlike_post"><img src="/images/karma-active.png" title="Undo Karma" /></a><a href="javascript:;" id="like_post" class="hide"><img src="/images/karma-inactive.png" title="Spread Karma" /></a></td><td><p id="counter"><?php echo $likecount; ?></p></td></tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </table>
</div>
<?php } else { ?>
<div id="karmabar">
    <table cellpadding="0px">
        <tr><td><a href="#" onclick="alert('Login with Facebook to Spread Karma');" ><img src="/images/karma-inactive.png" title="Spread Karma" /></a><td><p id="counter"><?php echo $likecount; ?></p></td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

$businessid and $userid are both defined higher up on the page.

like.php

```
<?php
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/db_connect.php';
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/functions.php';
$userid = $_GET['userid'];
$businessid = $_GET['businessid'];
$IP = $mysqli->real_escape_string(getClientIP());
$like_status = $_GET['like_status'];
if ($stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("SELECT count(id)
    FROM votes
    WHERE userid=? and businessid=? ")) {
        $stmt -> bind_param('ss', $userid, $businessid);
        $stmt -> execute();
        $stmt ->bind_result($count);
        $stmt ->fetch();
        $stmt ->close();
}
if ($count == '1') {
    if ($stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("UPDATE votes 
    SET ip=?, status=?
    WHERE userid=? and businessid=? ")) {
        $stmt -> bind_param('ssss', $IP, $like_status, $userid, $businessid);
        $stmt -> execute();
        $stmt -> close();
        $mysqli -> close();
    }
}
if ($count == '0') {
    if ($stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("INSERT INTO votes (userid, businessid, ip, status) 
    VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ? ) ")) {
        $stmt -> bind_param('ssss', $userid, $businessid, $IP, $like_status );
        $stmt -> execute();
        $stmt -> close();
        $mysqli -> close();
    }
}
?>
```

I appreciate any help that you guys can give me. Like I said, I'm new to this kind of coding and looking for any pointers that you may have.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but you should be pulling the user id from their authentication token.. as is, the user can change the user id parameter, allowing them to like pages for other users.

Comment: Also, note that ajax is async, so if you want the toggle to happen after the ajax request completes, that code needs to be in the success handler.

Comment: Absolutely what @JasonP said.  You could be fooling yourself into thinking it's successful.  Have you tried to purposely make the callback fail?  You aren't returning anything from your php page, so AJAX only knows if it connected to and talked to your PHP file - Your file MAY have incorrect paths now that it's on a server, rather than localhost

Comment: As a sidenote, if you're including user ID's, you might as well send the information as a `$_POST`.  Again, as @JasonP said, a user can just go to the script page and put any number he wants in

Comment: @JasonP I'll look more into that once I get this working properly.

Comment: @ntgCleaner The database does update while the page is loading, but as soon as it stops, it won't update anymore. I'm really not a coder, I just modify things until they work, but this has really got me stumped. It works perfectly for the 10 seconds or so it takes to load my page (my internet connection is really slow), but once it is fully loaded, it just stops doing what it's suppose to. There are no connection issues or anything because it does work at first. Are there any noticeable issues with my code, because like I said, this is all new to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mike, I'm not sure what's going on, but maybe you can try using this type of ajax request / PHP returns to trouble shoot:

Replace your entire AJAX function with this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#like_post').click(function() {
        $.post("/includes/like.php", {userid:<?php echo $userid; ?>, businessid:<?php echo $businessid; ?>, like_status:"1"}, function(data){
            alert(data); //Check to see what is being returned
            if(data == 1){ //Later, you can echo "1" in your PHP file on success
                //This is success
                alert("Success");
                $('#counter').html(function(i, val) { return val*1+1 });
                $('#like_post').hide();
                $('#unlike_post').show();
            } else {
                //This is failure
                alert("Failure");
            }
        });
    });

    $('#unlike_post').click(function() {
        $.post("/includes/like.php", {userid:<?php echo $userid; ?>, businessid:<?php echo $businessid; ?>, like_status:"0"}, function(data){
            alert(data); //Check to see what is being returned
            if(data == 1){ //Later, you can echo "1" in your PHP file on success
                //This is success
                alert("Success");
                $('#counter').html(function(i, val) { return val*1-1 });
                $('#unlike_post').hide();
                $('#like_post').show();
            } else {
                //This is failure
                alert("Failure");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And here would be the PHP - Notice, I changed your `$_GET`s to `$_POST`s and added an echo at the end.  I explain why after.

```
<?php
    include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/db_connect.php';
    include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/functions.php';
    $userid = $_POST['userid'];
    $businessid = $_POST['businessid'];
    $like_status = $_POST['like_status'];
    $IP = $mysqli->real_escape_string(getClientIP());
    if ($stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("SELECT count(id) FROM votes WHERE userid=? and businessid=? ")) {
        $stmt -> bind_param('ss', $userid, $businessid);
        $stmt -> execute();
        $stmt ->bind_result($count);
        $stmt ->fetch();
        $stmt ->close();
        echo "Got the count: " . $count;
    }
    if ($count == '1') {
        echo "The Count is 1";
        if ($stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("UPDATE votes SET ip=?, status=? WHERE userid=? and businessid=? ")) {
            $stmt -> bind_param('ssss', $IP, $like_status, $userid, $businessid);
            $stmt -> execute();
            $stmt -> close();
            $mysqli -> close();
            echo "And the post is successful (1)";
        }
    }
    if ($count == '0') {
        echo "The Count is 0";
        if ($stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("INSERT INTO votes (userid, businessid, ip, status) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ? ) ")) {
            $stmt -> bind_param('ssss', $userid, $businessid, $IP, $like_status );
            $stmt -> execute();
            $stmt -> close();
            $mysqli -> close();
            echo "And the post is successful (0)";
        }
    }
    echo "finished";
?>
```

Basically - I've added in a bunch of echos that you will be able to 'listen' to with your `$.post` ajax call when it returns the data. If everything is successful, you should get a sentence returned saying something like "Got the count: 1TheCount is 1 And the post is successful(1)Finished".  All of those echos should fire when the post is successful.  If you don't get one of those sentences, something has gone wrong.

Try this to trouble shoot and let us know what comes back.

Comment: When I use that code then nothing works at all. Perhaps there is something wrong with my original request. I have added the entire code above. Basically I had a working script of a like/unlike function, but it wasn't checking to see if the user had previously liked a page. So I had to modify the script to first run a check and display the proper output. I'd say I know about 90% of what's going on with that code, so I'm sure there is something wrong with that other 10%. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @miket414 Have you checked your console? done some troubleshooting? You have said it was working as the page was loading, but then it doesn't when it's loaded.  Have you checked your console on that load?

Comment: I'm getting this error  "ReferenceError: ? is not defined" Where ? is my current userid

Comment: @miket414 try hard coding valid info on the userid, businessid and like status into your java script instead of using php echos. Then see if you still get an error

Comment: Okay, I'm not getting that error anymore with echoed values or hard coded values. Maybe it was a cache error? Anyway, now when I click on the image link console returns 200 OK.  Then there is a popup without anything on it. When I click okay, I get a second popup that shows Failure. So I guess that's progress. =) The images still don't change and there is no writing to the database going on.

Comment: @miket414 Definitely shows promise! So the blank alerts are possibly php returning nothing and the java script is just alerting the null data returned. Try using 'or die()'  commands in your php queries and you should get some more info

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, I got it to work. Your original code was doing the trick, but I had pasted it wrong. Appreciate your patience with me. Thanks for teaching me a thing or 20. =)

Comment: @miket414 you got it! I'm always happy to help! And I'm glad it's all working out now

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like a connection error. Have you changed your connection parameters from your localhost to your live site. i.e. your database name and password to connect to?

Comment: I can connect to the database without issues and update the database the way it's suppose to as long as I do it as the page is loading. As soon as the page has finished loading 100%, I can't do this anymore. I have tried to deactivate all my other scripts thinking that maybe there was some conflict, but it made no difference. I'm not just relying on the result('Success') either, I am physically in the database and witnessing the updates taking place. I can update the database repeatedly as the page is loading and notice all the changes, but once the page is finished loading, this stops.